# How to check the functionality of all the pins on stm32?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, water, pc

What happened: I was carrying my stm32 f401re inside a bag, and there was a little droplets of water inside the bag, when I removed the bag the MCU was wet, I wiped it gently on my clothes before connecting it to the PC, and it worked with LEDs and the buttons.

Comment: PCBs are often literally washed in a water-based solution, so getting it wet is no problem. Just have it dry properly before you'll be using it. Leave it for a day in the back of a car sitting in the sun, for example.

Comment: Great thanks for the relief, I tried before asking this question And it worked properly but I was afraid that some of pins are not, as I am a beginner and still learning how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where I work,  I design and build circuitboards, usually based on MCUs.  When I finish a batch of boards I put them into a literal dish-washer.

Like this:
[image]

As long as they are dry before applying power, no problem at all.  Circuitboards and ICs are made to be washed.

If it works, it works.  I wouldn't bother trying to test the pins individually.

Comment: Upper or lower tray? With heated dry or without? :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Both upper and lower trays.  For production: No heated drying, they get a diH2O rinse then go into a special dryer we made that pumps filtered air @ 40C through the chamber.  Prototypes get the heated drying and no diH2O rinse, if I bother to wash them at all (depends on what the board does).